# angular and asp.net core 3.1 cors policy

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to connect my angular front end to my ASP.Net core 3.1 ef backend but am having CORS policy issues. I've tried everything I could find on this site but no luck, I'm not sure what I'm missing. I tweaked a few pieces of my code based on what I found here from other posts was was able to change the CORS error to a 400 bad request error, below is my startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using backend.Context;
using backend.Middleware;
using backend.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace backend
{
    public class Startup
    {
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
          services.AddCors(options =>
         {
             options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
             {

                 builder.AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyOrigin();



             });
         });




            services.AddDbContext<NineToFiveContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
            (Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlConnection")));


            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(s =>
            {
                s.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });

            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

            services.AddScoped<IUserRepo, SqlUserRepo>();

            services.AddScoped<IJobRepo, SqlJobRepo>();

            services.AddScoped<IFaqRepo, SqlFaqRepo>();


        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();




            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();


            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);


            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding some middleware based on a similar post on this site but it didn't work either, here's the middleware

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace backend.Middleware
{
    public class CorsMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public CorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Access-Control-Allow-Origin"))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            }
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally one post said the issue was with his connection string, mine is below. I think it is OK but not 100% sure as I am just on my practicum .

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "SQLConnection": "Server=xxx; Database=9ineTo5iveDB; Trusted_Connection=True"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've tried have the cors policy at the three different levels as per the microsoft documentation but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add  http://localhost:4200 in builder.WithOrigins

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod());
```